# How do i convert 5 single digit numbers

Tags: python, variables

I have 5 different variables;

```
a=4
b=5
c=7
d=9
e=8
```

I want to print them as 45798 and assign this value to another variable. How do I do this?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: `int(str(a) + str(b) + str(c) + str(d) + str(e))`

Comment: Can any of them be negative?

Comment: Having them in separate variables (rather than one list or so) is probably already a mistake.

Comment: The problem is not defined well enough. Should the result be a string or an integer again? What are you actually trying to achieve? Cause I agree with @StefanPochmann Therefore it's possibly an example of XY problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 3):

```
value = a * 10000 + b * 1000 + c * 100 + d * 10 + e
```

A general approach would be:

```
my_list = [e,d,c,b,a]
for index, element in enumerate(my_list):
    value += element * (10 ** index)
```

Comment: can you generalize this for an arbitrary number of initial variables ?

Comment: You can, with a for loop and all your integers in the same list. You just have to sum every integer multiplied by 10 with exponent equal to the index of the integer in the list

Comment: Exactly ☺! code the exponential please.

Comment: There you have ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
string_number = ''.join([str(x) for x in [a,b,c,d,e]])
int_number = int(string_number)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
e + 10 * (d + 10 * (c + 10 * (b + 10 * a)))
```

Do yo see the pattern? You can make a loop for any number of digits:

```
digits = (a, b, c, d, e)
result = 0
for n in digits:
    result = 10 * result + n
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not put them in a *container*, say a `tuple`, and then use `format`:

```
>>> nums = (a,b,c,d,e)
>>>
>>> int(('{}'*len(nums)).format(*nums))
45798
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
>>> sum(e*10**i for i,e in enumerate([e,d,c,b,a]))
45798
```

Comment: Another way for sum to work which is interesting!

Answer (score 0):

An arbitrary amount of input is the perfect example for `*args`.

```
def create_num(*args):
    return int(''.join(str(x) for x in args))

print(create_num(4, 5, 7, 9, 8))  # prints -> 45798
```

The `create_num` function can run with any number of values provided.